# Filled imagearc

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to draw a arc (part of circle) that is filled with semi transparent color. Is that possible?
I have found Imagearc but that only draws the line, and there is the imagefilledarc that draws 3d shaped arcs.
And there is eclipse which draws complete circles.

None of those do what I need. What can I use to get the image from:
[image]

To: (please try to look beyond my paint skills)

[image]

I have the angle of the main wind which is 150 degrees, and the wind variation 120-190 degrees, but how do I draw that semi transparent filled arc?
EDIT; I also have the centerpoint, and the diameter of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [`imagefilledarc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php) *is* the correct function for this. It doesn't draw 3D shapes - that is simply the example given in the PHP manual.

Using your first image with this code...

```
imagefilledarc(
    $im, // gd image resource
    512, // centre point x
    325, // centre point y
    285, // width (keep same as height for a perfect circle)
    285, // height (keep same as width for a perfect circle)
    120-90, // start (-90 degrees to start from 12 o'clock)
    190-90, // end (-90 degrees to start from 12 o'clock)
    0x40ff0000, // colour (50% transparent red)
    IMG_ARC_PIE
);
```

...gives me this result:

[image]

All you should need to do is replace the parameters with your calculated values (centre points, diameter, etc.).

Comment: That is amazing! I'm currently in bed due to fever so I can't test the code but it looks correct. I will accept when I have tested the code, probably tomorrow. Thank you very much!